# getElementById Not Required. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

In the process of switching my native javascript code to JQuery, I've noticed that even after deleting a variable that is referenced by `getElementById`, other part of code was still able to reference that element.

Why didn't I get an error? How's this good practice in ANY scenario?

```js
container1.innerHTML = "How did I not cause an error?";
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container1"></div>
</body>
```